# How to search by array

Tags: node.js, couchdb, couchdb-nano

I have some documents with the following format:

```
{
 url: 'some-unique-url',
 name: 'some-name'
}
```

What I need to do is to select the documents which has a specific url by supplying an array which contains the url's which I need to select:

```
['some-unique-url', 'another-url']
```

Here's what my view currently looks like:

```
function(doc) {
  if(doc.type == 'message'){
    emit([doc.url], null);
  }
}
```

And here's my node.js code. I'm using [nano](https://github.com/dscape/nano).

```
db.view('message', 'by_url', {'key': urls}, function(err, body){
    res.send(body);
});
```

This works if I only have one item in the array but as soon as I add another item, here's what I get:

```
{"total_rows":18,"offset":11,"rows":[]}
```

I also tried `startkey` and `endkey` which also works but it acts the same way as the previous one:

```
db.view('message', 'by_url', {'startkey': online_users_ids, 'endkey': [online_users_ids, {}]}, function(err, body){
    res.send(body);
});
```

Is what I'm trying to do possible with couchdb and nano? If not, what's the closest thing I can get without losing performance? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `keys` instead of `key` as documented in the [CouchDB API Reference](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/api/ddoc/views.html).

```
db.view('message', 'by_url', {'keys': urls}, function(err, body){
    res.send(body);
});
```